# validating UpdateData(true) return value in MFC OnTimer routine

Tags: c++, timer, mfc

I am working on an MFC application(VS2017).
In that I have a made one second timer. Inside the `OnTimer()` routine along with my business logic I am calling `UpdateData(FALSE)` to show some runtime info back to UI.

Also, I have to get some user input from the UI for that inside the user Input Event handler, I am calling `UpdateData(TRUE)` and checking its return value in `OnTimer` routine.

Problem is since the timer is an independent entity here. Even though I have guarded the `UpdateData(FALSE)` inside `OnTimer` the `UpdateData(FALSE)` is getting executed for a blank user input, which crashes the program by calling assert.

```
/***SAMPLE Problem CODE****/`
void abc::OnEnUserInput()
{
    IsvalidInput = UpdateData(TRUE);
}

void abc::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    if (IsvalidInput == true) 
    {
     UpdateData(FALSE);
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!
Thanks.

Comment: Show more about the crash. Show the call stack.

Comment: for a blank input it throws an exception that "Enter a positive Integer." along with one more debug assertion failed window...

Comment: The easiest thing would be to use `GetDlgItemText` for the corresponding edit control, do the check if the string is a valid positive integer and if not don't call `UpdateData(FALSE)`.

Comment: which line in DoDataExchange is throwing the assert? Add code of that line.

Comment: did you initialized `IsvalidInput` to FALSE?

Comment: @zar nops... initialized to true.

Answer (score 0):

Got my solution earlier itself but due to the busy schedule couldn't get time to share it.

for avoiding this issue I opened another dialogue box to receive the user input, since `UpdatedData(FALSE)` in `OnTimer()` is in background dialogue box so the user input in child dialog `UpdateData(TRUE)` will not interfare with background `UpdatedData(FALSE)`.